# (Python) Separating lists when printing

Tags: python, code-separation

I am writing a code for school and we need to make a deck of cards as part of it. I have already made the deck but I do not know how to print it the way I want it. It either prints with all the brackets and commas or none. My goal is to print it with a comma separating every two values of the list. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us how you're printing the deck, and the output it makes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's way, maybe not the best result:

```
cards = ['3','A','7','Q','4']
print(f'"{", ".join(cards)}"')
```

Output:

```
"3, A, 7, Q, 4"
```